# HTML5 ajax client-server communication and security

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html

thanks for your help today. I am creating an HTML5 game and need some help determining the best method for Client Server communications.

I am trying to avoid socket.io for reasons I cannot mention.

The primary thing is that the app needs to be secure(i.e. not open to js injection), while minimizing server load as much as possible

I understand that Ajax is one such method and the Jquery has some easy Ajax methods in its library.

I am not looking for any code, only advice on what the best way to go about this.

Let me provide and over simplified example

I have 1 div, and 2 buttons. The div displays # of coins, the first button adds 1 coin every time it is clicked, the 2nd button is upgrade coins button, which will subtract a certain number of coins.

all of the addition and subtraction of coins will be handled server side. My understanding is if I use session variables to store the data on the server, that they are invulnerable to "cheat engine" or other memory editing tools. Correct me if I am wrong on this.

So when the user clicks the add coin button the coins div will increase by 1 or some greater amount later. I understand that can be done very simply with something like

```
$("#div1").load("update.php");
```

so is this vulnerable to js injection, inother words can someone alter it to add more than 1 coin when it is clicked, my thinking is probably not.

finally is it possible to update more than 1 element from the same jquery request, for example if I want to change both "div1" and "div2" from the same request or is it best to do that as 2 separate requests? also lets say that there is more than 1 piece of data returned by the request. Is this where a Json file would come in handy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best advice (as frontend/game dev) I can give you is "Never trust user input"

Any user can inject, edit or remove any request done with JS/JQuery (chrome console, proxy...). You have to verify all user input server side.

For exemple, check if the user car earn money, level... at this moment.

Be also aware that if the user can win that money or level .. it can also be an error in your frontend code :)

Hope this can help...

Regards,

Comment: thanks for the response, I was looking for a little bit more though.

Comment: My understanding is that, if all of the variables and calculations are done server side, that is I check if they have enough coins before I allow the upgrade to be purchased. Since the only data I will accept from the client is the ID of the pressed button, then I have a function on the server that does different things depending on which ID was posted. My understand would be the most the user could do is use an auto-clicker to make faster requests. Has this been your experience as well?

Comment: You can do all your calculation server side but you will encounter an other trouble(mainly on low connections): the interval between the click and the answer. 
For exemple your user click on the button "buy" but his money is not reduced until request is complete... bad user experience!
You have to do the calculation client side (reduce money) and confirm it server side and re-update client side.

Comment: A bad user can also;
- send you out-of-bounds integer (ex: Max Int + 100) 
- send you, for exemple a string "Hello" in money params
- many, many, many other options!

A bad user can:
- Corrupt his data
- Corrupt all your data ;)

Comment: question about your response.

Comment: if the button simply sends an id number and I have an array on the server of acceptable id#s, anything that is not in the array is ignored. Also if the money is stored in a server variable, sure they could hit the buy button before it updates, but that wont accomplish anything since the money will still be subtracted on the server. They will not be able to use the button if they don't have enough money. Sure there may be a delay of a second before they get a message saying they dont have enough money but so what. I am more concerned about users doing things they shouldn't

Comment: Seems to be more secured like this but, of course, that depends of the rest of your code :)